# Rails 3 Contact Form, undefined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, contact-form

I'm building a contact form in Rails 3 using this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr?view=asciicast

I know that the only thing I'm doing wrong is filling out where the message should be sent. I used the following code to send the message:

```
mail(:to => "me@myemail.com")
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, because everytime I submit the form, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in MessagesController#create

undefined method `mail' for #<MessagesController:0x00000103734bd8>

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

What should I replace this line with to send the message?

**messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    if @message.valid?
      UserMailer.contact_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

end
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

def contact_message(message)
@message = message
mail(:to => "myemail@mymail.com", :subject => "New Message")
end

end
```

**setup_mail.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => "mywebsite.com",
:user_name            => "myemail",
:password             => "secret",
:authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: You have an application controller and not an Action Mailer

Answer (score 0):

there's no object created on the mail variable on your controller. Actualy to user Mailer on rails you don't have to instantiate a variable just call you mailer with the method. Like:

```
YourMailer.send(params)
```

You can always go to rails guides to see how some stuff works:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

The Message object you're creating is just an object that can be used in a form with validations. You still need to actually create a Mailer object, and fill it with the name/email/message that you get from the @message object.

If you create a Mailer (see [Episode 206 - Action Mailer](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3)), and you'd do something like this in your controller after creating a `MessageMailer`

```
def create
  if @message.valid?
    MessageMailer.contact_message(@message).deliver
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form is awesome -- takes the concept one step and combines into one class.

Comment: OK...I followed your advice and watched Episode 206. I've added the changes I've made above. When I submit the contact form now, it successfully redirects to the home page, but no email is sent to me, and there is no notice stating that the message was sent. What am I missing?

Comment: Change this to true in your config/environments/development.rb to see if any failures are occurring: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17883328/307308

You are missing the `from` attribute in your mail method.

```
mail(:from => 'system@mymail.com', :to => "myemail@mymail.com", :subject => "New Message")
```